# How can i stop flask form textbox from blurring entire form when clicked on?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, flask-wtforms

So I am trying to make a simple RESTful API using Python Flask with an email, first name, last name, password and submit field just to play around with python. What I noticed is that if I click any of the fields, the entire form slightly blurs and it bothers my eyes a little bit

Here's the code provided. There's more to it but these are the main code for this issue

```
style.css

:root {
    background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 121, 96, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
    font-family: lato;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    color: white;

}

.form {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 25px;
    max-width: 500px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    gap: 30px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

```
base.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= , initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <p id="Name"></p>

            <body onload="beginTypingAnimation('Name','Malik Zurkiyeh',1250)"></body>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div>
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
 
    <div id="about" class="about">
        <p>lol</p>
    </div>

    <script src="../static/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
signup.html

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Signup{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form">

        <h2>Signup</h2>
        <p>
            {{form.email.label}}: &nbsp; {{form.email(size=30)}} <br>
        </p>

        <p>
            {{form.first_name.label}}: &nbsp; {{form.first_name(size=30)}} <br>

        </p>

        <p>
            {{form.last_name.label}}: &nbsp; {{form.last_name(size=30)}} <br>
        </p>


        <p>
            {{form.password.label}}: &nbsp; {{form.password(size=30)}} <br>
        </p>

        <p>{{form.submit(class_="submit_button")}}</p>

        <div class="message">
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

```
forms.py

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm as fm
from wtforms import StringField as stf, PasswordField as pf, SubmitField as sf


class Sign_up(fm):
    first_name = stf("First Name")
    last_name = stf("Last Name")
    email = stf("E-mail")
    password = pf("Password")
    submit = sf("Submit")
```

Comment: maybe remove all `css` and start from beginning

Comment: could you add screenshot to show problem?